# Access Query Distinguishing columns using parameter

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2013

I am trying to modify certain fields in an access db, but I was hoping I can do it in one query.
Looking for something like this:

`PARAMETERS [PID] long, [PColumnName] Text (100);`
`UPDATE Employees SET [PColumnName] = 0`
`WHERE ID=[PID];`

And I can input the [PColumnName] parameter as the column I want to change to zero.
Now I don't actually want to change anything to zero, I am just really asking if there is anyway to do this?

If it isn't possible, it's not a big deal, I can just make separate queries for each column, but for the future I would love to know of someway to do this.

Suggestions are welcome, I'm relatively new to this so I'll take all the help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to write the query as SQL:

```vb
SQL = "UPDATE Employees SET [{0}] = 0 WHERE ID = {1};"
SQL = Replace(SQL, "{0}", PColumnName)
SQL = Replace(SQL, "{1}", PID)
CurrentDb.Execute SQL
```